# Windows add to path from command line

Tags: java, windows, path, chocolatey

When using Boxstarter and or Chocolatey it is difficult to install JDK properly to use with Maven and other tools.

How can I add to environmental variables?

```
setx -m path "C:\java"
```

but this will clear previous environmental variable.

Suggesing this was a duplicate:I said I wanted "add" to the ev's not "set" and I was clearly looking for a cmd script

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: This is clearly a command line question not a general question on using GUIs @cricket_007.

Comment: And there are methods listed in that question for setting the CMD

Comment: Although, you _should_ be setting it at the system level, not once per terminal session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Powershell append test suggestion. Note the limitation of Windows previous to Windows 10.

Windows 8- WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

`Powershell -Command " setx -m pathtest \"$env:path ";" $env:JAVA_HOME\""`

Answer (score 1):

You should add new path to end of current path with this:

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;<your-new-path>"
```

So in your case it will be like this:

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\java"
```

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> setx /M PATHa "%PATHa%;C:\java"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> setx /M PATHa "%PATHa%;C:\java"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> setx /M PATHa "%PATHa%;C:\javal"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> setx /M PATHa "%PATHa%;C:\javall"

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
creates %PATHa%;C:\javall what does that do?

Comment: @user1198289 so?

Comment: @user1198289 It's just `%PATH%`, not `%PATHa%` nor `javall`

Comment: Never use setx.exe to define `PATH`. This variable is defined in terms of other variables that get expanded at load time (e.g. `%UserProfile%`). More importantly, its definition is split into a per-machine value and a per-user value that get concatenated at load time. By updating it as `"%PATH%;<your-new-path>"`, you make a horrible mess of both implementation details.

Comment: @user1198289 This is why I accepted your answer and your example is spot on.

Comment: @ErykSun, that is brilliant note which isn't obvious for not very experienced users like myself. That solution with `SETX` looks really nice and appealing, and I've almost run that `SETX` command happily. Good thing I came across your comment before. 
Looks like we have to do it directly via Windows registry.

Comment: @ErykSun, I found [decent article](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/) about getting and setting registry values from the command line, but they say there is no proper command-line way to make OS recognize new values.

Comment: This answer will delete everything you have in your system path and set it's new value to `"%PATH%;C:\java"` So please don't use this , if you must try it make sure that you have backed up your system path before trying.