# Can't open java files in Windwos

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So i was going to instal libGDX but was unable to open the .jar file. 
I did some serching and found some threads to my problem. But none of them worked.

I have installed JavaSE and set the JAVA_HOME to the path of jdk 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"

I have tried to doubleclick the setupfile, but nothing happens. 
I have tried to run the file from the cmd. But when i try to run the file from there or check for my java verion with "java -version" the only thing i get back is:
"java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

This problem, from what i have read, would be solved by checking/change the JAVA_HOME filepath. Am i missing something here? I still can't open the .jar file despite following the steps in some other threads.

TIA

Comment: Try adding `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable. See how to set it up on other systems [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).
You can also refer to this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need use a "Java SE Development Kit 8"
download here

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html