# My java program runs in netbeans, but will not run in command or through the jar file. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

So, I am trying to run a program from jar files. It uses javaswing and has a gui.

The program runs fine in netbeans and in eclipse.

When I try to run it from the exported jar file it says this:

Unable To Install Java
There are errors in the following switches:
"C:\Users\CNC Department\Desktop\ValveConversion.jar";.

Check that the commands are valid and try again.[java installation not complete
Now, I also tried doing it from the command prompt. Here is what came up:
[cmd prompt attempt][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7reZ3.png

So, I reinstalled the java JDK, java SDK, netbeans and eclipse. The issue is still occurring in both command prompt and from running the jar file directly.

What am I doing incorrectly here? What do you recommend that I do to get this to run from a .jar file?

Comment: You need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: To run commands (.exe files) their location need to be in `path` system variable.

Comment: Take a look at [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672281).

Comment: Pshemo, I tried it, https://imgur.com/a/dlKmnBP

Comment: Lppedd and Pshemo, So, I followed pshemo's guide. https://imgur.com/a/QBCI24K Here is my present configuration.

Comment: I added this in uservariables to just to be sure, https://imgur.com/a/qyu1gSI

Comment: Same message when I attempt it in command prompt.

Comment: If you don't want to set a PATH var you can always execute it as follows:


`C:\Downloads/Software/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar C:\Users\CNC Department\Desktop\ValveConversion.jar`

Comment: I feel like I am missing something here. PS, I tried your cmd input Roberto Manfreda https://imgur.com/a/Wg4olVn

Comment: This was an example... you have to modify that path with the path of your downloaded jdk if you have any!

Comment: Shoot thanks. I figured that out after the fact. It ended up giving me this new error. I think we're getting closer. https://imgur.com/a/tAUsjmU

Comment: Please wrap the path with double quotes. Beacuse in your path are some white spaces. Or escape the white spaces if you don't want to wrap strings. `C:\Downloads/Software/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar "C:\Users\CNC Department\Desktop\ValveConversion.jar"`

Comment: Roberto Manfreda, thank you so much! You rock! Success! https://imgur.com/a/r16WcXF

Comment: Yes but is better if you set the PATH running this from a cmd (with elevated privileges): `setx JAVA_HOME -m "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"`then restart cmd and run `where java` and `java -version` just to be sure that it's all ok. Now you can use the java command just calling `java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to set the java path**
Open a cmd with elevated privileges and run this command to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable using `setx` command:

```
setx JAVA_HOME -m "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"
```

Then restart the cmd and run `java -version` to check if it's all ok.
For reference [setx command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)

**Or simply use the following snippet if you prefer to use java without setting the PATH variable:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" -jar "C:\Users\CNC Department\Desktop\ValveConversion.jar"
```