# Don't know how to get java compiler to run HelloWorld, tried everything

Tags: java

To begin with I carefully copied and pasted the pathway for `javac` into the *System Variable Editing box in Advanced System Settings*, making sure to carefully put it at the beginning and placing a `;` after `bin`, before the other parts.

Then I followed the Oracle tutorial for the `HelloWorldApp` to the letter, setting up a my application folder and creating a notepad file inside.

Subsequent to all this, I opened the command shell in windows and punched in my script; hit `dir;` got the spiel about files and such; entered `javac HelloWorldApp.java` to only end invariably with:

> "Javac not a recognised command"

*Arrgh* what am I doing wrong? Is it, as I suspect--that the `Java SE12` isn't loaded properly (there is no `.exe` after my `javac` file).

- Am I not saving the notepad file correctly? (ie HelloWorld?)
- Am I not editing the path for the javac compiler properly?

[image: 1]

Comment: You forgot to add your screenshots. With that little detail, we can only guess, which is outside of the frame defined by [answer]. Your question might get down-voted or closed, please see [ask], thanks.

Comment: Can we see your path entry? Looks like you're on Windows 10 and you wouldn't need to add the ; as Windows 10 does that for you.

Comment: After editing the Path environment variable, you might want to restart the computer for it to reread the added entry

Comment: Yes we need more information on question and I understand your frustration. Try giving screenshots and meanwhile as a workaround, instead of javac HelloWorldApp.java try giving <location of javac> HelloWorldApp.java. For example if javac is in C:\jdk\bin\ then give C:\jdk\bin\javac HelloWorldApp.java

Comment: @AlmostHandsome: There's no need to reboot. Just restarting the command prompt is fine.

Comment: `javac` is an executable file placed under the `bin` folder for your **JDK** installation. The first thing to check, is that you installed a JDK. If you have a "simple" JRE, `javac` is not included.

Go to the folder where Java is installed, then under `bin`, and check if `javac.exe` is present.

Comment: Then, check if `javac` is available from the command line by using `javac -version`.. It should print something like `javac 1.8.0_60`; if `javac` is not found, you have to double check your `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Last time what you said did not do it for me, had to kill the current session by logging out and in again

Comment: @AlmostHandsome: If you've set environment variables via the control panel applet, a new command prompt definitely picks them up. I do that regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The first step will be to verify Java is set up correctly.

1. Open the command prompt.
2. Type "java -version".
3. Press enter.
   This should return the version of java you are running. Something like:
   java version "1.8.0_151"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
4. Add the path to java to your system path.

[image]

See these two links if you have trouble adding java to the system path.

https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/dcs/people/research/csrcbc/teaching/howto/javapath/

[Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

5. Once this is set try "java -version" again.  (make sure to open a new command window) Only after this works try the "javac" command.