# How to ensure Java JDK and JRE match and how to make them match if they dont

Tags: java, runtime

I have been trying to get my JDK and JRE to match for a couple hours now, but do not know what to do. Any help appreciated.

I've checked the versions and realized they are different. I have already installed the latest JDK but do not know how to change the JRE to match the JDK.

javac -version
javac 12.0.1

java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"

C:\Users\jacob\OneDrive\Desktop\Code>java Ah
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Ah has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I expect to be able to have the same versions so that my code will run, but it will not run.

Comment: The latest JRE can be found [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).

Comment: JDK contains JRE.

Comment: I would try installing the JRE separately anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the environment variable for `javac` ( java compiler ) is pointing to a different version compared to the environment variable for `java`( java run-time ) command.

Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/11414745) and set up the correct environment variables.

Comment: The JRE path appears to be generic (i.e. not version-specific).

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling JRE and only install JDK. It worked for me.