# Javac JOptionPane cannot find symbol: showMesssageDialog

Tags: java, javac

What could be the problem? I have added the javac file path in the environment variable. The JOptionPane showMesssageDialog symbol is not found!!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class MassageDialog1{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password");
    }

}
```

[image]
Here, ClassNotFoundException
[image: Second error]
More Error: 
What is going on here??
[image]

Comment: It's a typo, there is a superfluous `s` in what should be `showMessageDialog` .

Comment: Should I delete the question ?

Comment: Well you can, or it will be closed as off-topic since it is a typo anyway.

Comment: What is JNI error

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008502/how-to-ensure-java-jdk-and-jre-match-and-how-to-make-them-match-if-they-dont