# I am trying to download android studio but it keeps telling me to install Java which i have done so. Please tell me what i should do?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download android studio but it keeps telling me that i need to update or install Java, which i have done so afew times. But it keeps giving me the Java error message. I am running this on MacOS Mojave version 10.14.5. This is what the error keeps saying:

Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.

Comment: Did you set path? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure to install the latest JDK 12 from below link

   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html
2. Configure the JVM and verify with command "java -version"
3. If above tasks has completed, retry the installation process.@naj

Comment: ive tried this and it helps. Thanks alot for yor help.

Comment: cheers ! It's good to know that you have sorted the issue@naj

Answer (score 0):

To  `verify` whether you have install `JAVA` correctly or not in your machine. Do like below :

- Open `Command Prompt` and Type : `java -version`
- If it shows you the `version` then it all correct. But, if it does not recognize the command then you need to paste your jdk path in Environment variables. i.e : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin`

Comment: If it helps you then don't forget to up-vote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the JAVA_HOME Variable

- Windows: [configure java_home guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)
- Mac: [configure java home guide](http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Naj you are welcome, and if it work remember to give me a point pressing "this answer is useful"