# Showing Error after installation of Android Studio 32bit

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: showing error after installation of Android Studio]

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.
Error status 0xc000035a
```

Comment: You must define the JDK path in your system environment. Please follow this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Answer (score 0):

you need to install JDK, can be downloaded from: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html