# java not a recognised command error although PATH and JAVA_HOME set correctly

Tags: java, command-line-interface, javac

When trying to use java or javac in CMD, I get a

> 'java' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

error.

The jdk bin directory is set in path:

And the JAVA-HOME is set:

```
echo %PATH%
...C:\Program Files\jdk-12\bin...

echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT- more infomration

My PATH Config:
[image]

And JAVA_HOME:
[image]

Comment: Did you start a new CMD after setting the env variables?

Comment: Can you include the _entire_ value of `%PATH%`? Maybe it's pointing to the wrong subdirectory under the JDK. `%JAVA_HOME% is not relevant here; you can ignore that. Also, this is a program-configuration question, not a programming question, so probably belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @lainatnavi yes I restarted PC and CMD, i

Comment: Setting the PATH variable is enough to invoke `java` and `javac` under Windows. Can you try executing `where java` from the command line? For reference, try also executing `where cmd` ..

Comment: maybe that white space in "program files" is causing the issue? Can you move the java folder under `c:/programs/java` , edit the PATH var accordingly and retry?

Comment: @Daniele where java INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). where cmd C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Comment: OK so the `java/bin` folder is not present in your PATH variable. Are you using `;` as delimiters between folders in PATH?.

Comment: Just noticed the difference between what you have in the PATH and in JAVA_HOME. In PATH you are missing the \Java\ folder. Set it in the PATH like `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Hi All, have a look at question I have updated to demonstrate the PATH and JAVA_HOME vars

Comment: If this command works: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java.exe"` append it to the system path variable. `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin`.

Comment: The C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java.exe brought me to the executable , so I appended it to path var but am still getting same error...

Comment: Does the full path to the bin folder appear on the output of one of these: `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"` or `reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` ?

Comment: That returns  JAVA_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12...and the PATH returns ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Ive just noted this only appears to be an issue if I try to run the command in an eclipse work space

Comment: all the variables you need to for Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: install java manually other than windows default program files directory by using https://techviewleo.com/install-java-openjdk-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

When I had set the user environment variables they did not save, simple error. Anyway anyone with similar issues this is an excellent answer: [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)